# Write a generique line

Tags: php, symfony

I have a little problem in wanting to make a reusable code, this code allows me to save in a values ​​file, i show you what i currently have :

```
fputcsv($handle, array_keys($dataRepository[0]), ',');

foreach ($dataRepository as $key => $item) {
    fputcsv(
        $handle,
        [
            $item['id'],
            $item['email'],
            $item['firstName']
        ],
        ','
    );
}
```

on this piece of code, I add the ('id', 'email', 'firstName') because in my repository I have these elements, but for future re-use these fields will probably not be there and there will have others instead.

So here is my question, how could I generalize this part? I tried several cases that did not work like re doing a foreach etc ...

Comment: Pass fields' names as array to your function

Comment: thank you for the reaply, can you explain more please? i don't realy think i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code creating function and pass to it names of data as an array.

```
function customCSVFunction($handle, $dataRepository, $parametersArray)
{
    fputcsv($handle, array_keys($dataRepository[0]), ',');

    foreach ($dataRepository as $key => $item) {
        $items = [];
        foreach ($parametersArray as $parameter) {
            $items[] = $item[$parameter];
        }
        fputcsv($handle, $items, ',');
    }
}
```

And you can call it your function passing specific names of data you want to save into CSV.

```
$parametersArray = [
    'id', 'email', 'firstName'
];

customCSVFunction($handle, $dataRepository, $parametersArray);
```